# Encrypt JSON Web Token as RSA RS256 in Powershell with a RSA private key

Tags: powershell, encryption, jwt, rsa, docusignapi

I am stuck, I am trying to sign a Json Web Token for Docusign. https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken Docusign just provides a RSA private and public key hash. That's it. The JWT must signed using RS256.

I found a JWT module https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JWT/1.1.0 but that requires that I have the certificate installed. But all I have is the key hash.

Levering some other code I found I was able to create a JWT token , although with the wrong algorithm. https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/8bc3rb/generate_jwt_json_web_token_in_powershell/
I've been trying modify it to use the RSACryto provider by creating a new object but ive been unsuccessful.

I tried to create a new object and see if I can some how import the key so that I can sign the token. But I cant seem to be able to do that.

```
$rsa = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider
$keyhash = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
XXXXXX
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"

$blob = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes($keyhash))
```

I tried to use the ImportCspBlob method but it requires that the string is converted to bytes but I cant seem to do that either.

Im not sure if I am even approaching this int he correct fashion. Ive been getting errors of either

```
Exception calling "ImportCspBlob" with "1" argument(s): "Bad Version of provider.
or
Cannot convert value to type "System.Byte". Error: "Input string was not in a correct format."
```

EDIT: 
I have a work around using Node.js, although id still like to see if it is possible to do what I am trying to do natively in Powershell . This work aroun might be useful for some as there does not seem to be many references for using Powershell and Docusign API.

I found a node.JS script here that creates a JWT Token using the RS256 algorithm.  https://github.com/BlitzkriegSoftware/NodejwtRSA ,

I stripped out all the extra stuff so the output to the console is only the token, and added the relevant scope to the "payload data" and under the sign options updated the sub, aud, and iss. The my RSA Private key was stored locally on the system in a file.

nodejs script - My modified version below

```
'use strict';

const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

// https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');

// Private Key (must read as utf8)
var privateKey = fs.readFileSync('./rsatest.pk','utf8');
// Sample claims payload with user defined fields (this can be anything, but briefer is better):
var payload = { };
// Populate with fields and data
payload.scope = "signature impersonation";
// Values for the rfc7519 fields
var iss = "XXXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXX-XXX";
var sub = "XXXXX-XXXX-XXX-XXX-XXX";
var aud = "account-d.docusign.com";
// Expiration timespan: https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken#token-expiration-exp-claim
var exp = "1h";
// JWT Token Options, see: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7519#section-4.1 for the meaning of these
// Notice the `algorithm: "RS256"` which goes with public/private keys
var signOptions = {
    issuer : iss,
    subject: sub,
    audience: aud,
    expiresIn: exp,
    algorithm: "RS256"
};
var token = jwt.sign(payload, privateKey, signOptions);
console.log(token)
process.exitCode = 0;
```

I called it from Powershell and feed the access token back into my script so i can then get my access token and start making my API calls.

```
#get the JWT token
$token = & node C:\temp\nodejwt.js
# Generate Header for API calls.
$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
$body ="grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=$token"
$authuri = "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token"
#send the JWT and get the access token 
$accesstoken = Invoke-RestMethod -Method post -Uri $authuri -Headers $headers -Body $body -Verbose
$getheaders = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$getheaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
$getheaders.Add('Authorization','Bearer ' + $accesstoken.access_token)    
$geturi = "https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo"
#use the access token to make api calls 
Invoke-RestMethod -Method get -Uri $geturi -Headers $getheaders
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem and was stuck.I used Python to get JWT. Be sure to install PyJWT and cryptography library.

```
$ pip install PyJWT
$ pip install pyjwt[crypto]


import time
import jwt
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

private_key= b'-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
`-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n'

encoded_jwt = jwt.encode({
    "iss":"<service account e-mail>",
    "scope":"",
    "aud":"",
    "exp":int(time.time())+3600,
    "iat":int(time.time())
    }, private_key, algorithm='RS256')
encoded_jwt
```